# Orbeon deployment on JBoss AS 7

Tags: jboss, orbeon

We are trying to deploy Orbeon Forms 3.9 on JBoss AS 7 and getting the following errors:

```
15:34:36,621 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/adg-xforms]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListenerDelegate: org.orbeon.oxf.common.OXFException: no implementation of regexp was found.
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListenerDelegate.contextInitialized(OrbeonServletContextListenerDelegate.java:43) [orbeon.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.contextListenerStart(StandardContext.java:3368) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3821) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_25]

15:34:36,670 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Error listenerStart
15:34:36,670 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext] (MSC service thread 1-2) Context [/adg-xforms] startup failed due to previous errors
15:34:36,682 ERROR [stderr] (MSC service thread 1-2) Starting Orbeon Forms 3.8.0.201005141856 CE

15:34:36,693 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/adg-xforms]] (MSC service thread 1-2) Exception sending context destroyed event to listener instance of class org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListenerDelegate: org.orbeon.oxf.common.OXFException: Could not initialize class com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.AnyURIType
    at org.orbeon.oxf.webapp.OrbeonServletContextListenerDelegate.contextDestroyed(OrbeonServletContextListenerDelegate.java:52) [orbeon.jar:]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStop(StandardContext.java:3465) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.stop(StandardContext.java:3970) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.start(StandardContext.java:3888) [jbossweb-7.0.1.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.web.deployment.WebDeploymentService.start(WebDeploymentService.java:70) [jboss-as-web-7.0.2.Final.jar:7.0.2.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1824)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1759)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:886) [:1.6.0_25]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:908) [:1.6.0_25]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:662) [:1.6.0_25]
```

Do you support JBoss AS 7 or anyone tried deploying orbeon on this app server.

Answer (score 1):

I just added xsdlib-20030225.jar to lib directory (It's just one I had to hand ;-O). This is a HACK, I don't know what it affects and don't know if there are any side effects...but it works so far ;-)

This was tested with JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes".

Follow the following steps:

- for Orbeon Forms PE

  - unzip `orbeon.war`
  - place your `license.xml` file under `WEB-INF/resources/config/license.xml`
  - re-zip `orbeon.war`
- start a standalone server with `bin/standalone.sh`
- drop `orbeon.war` into the JBoss `standalone/deployments` folder

([source](http://wiki.orbeon.com/forms/doc/developer-guide/admin/installing#TOC-JBoss-7-with-Orbeon-Forms-4))

Answer (score 0):

The joy of class loaders. Some code in MSV tries to load `com.sun.msv.datatype.xsd.AnyURIType`, which shouldn't fail as this class is in `WEB-INF/lib/msv-xsdlib-20070407_orbeon_20100309.jar`. I suspect that because of the way the class loaders is structured in JBoss, Orbeon ends up using a version of MSV coming from JBoss which is unable to load `AnyURIType` which is a jar that only comes with Orbeon. But I might be wrong on this.

This type of application-server specific question can be rather time consuming to resolve. So I would recommend you to use Tomcat or to get Orbeon to resolve this for you under a [Development Support subscription](http://www.orbeon.com/support-services/development).